# Oracle/SQL - Multi-table join logic - Not sure how else to phrase it

Tags: sql, oracle

What I'm trying to do is find all customers who purchased a `Series X` or `Series A` widget the day prior as long as it was their first time purchasing a widget from that.  In the event they purchased more than one qualifying widget `Series X` takes rank and I should only get back a record for it.  Hopefully that makes sense so here's the data

```
[customers]
c_id     cp_id
--------------
1        cp1
2        cp2
3        cp3
4        cp4
5        cp5
6        cp6
7        cp7
8        cp8
9        cp9
10       cp10

[widget_orders - c_id maps to c_id in customers]
c_id    w_sku   o_date
----------------------
1       w1      2012-10-10
2       w1      2012-10-10
2       w2      2012-10-10
3       w1      2012-10-10
3       w2      2012-10-10
4       w1      2012-10-10
4       w2      2012-10-10
5       w1      2012-10-10
5       w2      2012-10-10
6       w1      2012-10-10
6       w2      2012-10-10
7       w2      2012-10-10
8       w1      2012-10-10
9       w3      2012-10-10

[widgets - w_sku maps to w_sku in widget_orders]
w_sku   w_series
------------------
w1      Series A
w2      Series X
w3      Series C

[customer_data - c_id maps to c_id in customers]
cp_id   seriesA_fPurch  seriesX_fPurch
--------------------------------------
cp3     
cp4     2012-09-15
cp5                     2012-09-15
cp6     2012-09-15      2012-09-15
cp7                     2012-09-15  
cp8     2012-09-15
```

And here is the data I would like to get back ignoring descriptions in ()

```
cp_id   series
--------------
cp1     Series A (bought series A and had NO prior purchase history)
cp2     Series X (bought both series, but X has rank - no purchase history)
cp3     Series X (bought both series, but X has rank - has purchase history recors albeit not for these)
cp4     Series X (bought both series, but X has rank - already had A history anyways)
cp5     Series A (bought both series, although X has rank they had previously bought series X)
```

The following people don't show in the results

```
cp6 - they had previously bought both series
cp7 - bought a series x, but had in the past
cp8 - bought a series a, but had in the past
cp9 - bought a widget in neither series
cp10 - didnt buy anything
```

Hope all that makes sense and someone could help me out here!

So to summarize the logic and perhaps define it a bit more clearly here is how I would describe what needs to happen in a step-like fashion

```
1) Find all customers who have no matching records in the customer_data table
2) Find all customers who have a null value in either *purch column in the customer_data table
3) Combine these results together
4) Take the results and find the customers who made a purchase yesterday
5) Take the results and find the customers who purchased Series A or Series X
6) Take the results and do the following
    6a) If the purchase was Series A and they have a value for series A purch already drop them from results
    6b) If the purchase was Series X and they have a value for series X purch already drop them from results
7) Take the results and remove duplicate records based on the cp_id - Series X takes presedence over Series A
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your requirement completely, but try:

```
SELECT cp_id, w_series
FROM (
SELECT rank() over (partition BY wo."c_id" ORDER BY decode(w."w_series",'Series X',1,'Series A',2)) rank,
       wo."c_id" c_id,
       c."cp_id" cp_id,
       w."w_series" w_series
FROM widget_orders wo JOIN widgets w ON wo."w_sku"=w."w_sku"
  JOIN customers c on c."c_id"=wo."c_id"
LEFT OUTER JOIN customer_data cd ON c."cp_id" = cd."cp_id"
WHERE  w."w_series" IN ('Series A', 'Series X')
  AND  trunc(wo."o_date") = trunc(sysdate)-1
  AND ( (cd."seriesA_fPurch" IS NULL AND w."w_series"='Series A')
     OR (cd."seriesX_fPurch" IS NULL AND w."w_series"='Series X'))
  )
WHERE rank = 1
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1ae00/5) is a fiddle

Explanation:
according to the step-like numbers-
1) + 2) Are done in the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` + `cd."seriesA_fPurch" IS NULL` condition + `cd."seriesX_fPurch" IS NULL` condition since it will find also those who have no records and put nulls in them.
3) obvious...
4) `trunc(wo."o_date") = trunc(sysdate)-1` condition
5) `w."w_series" IN ('Series A', 'Series X')`
6) `(cd."seriesA_fPurch" IS NULL AND w."w_series"='Series A')
         OR (cd."seriesX_fPurch" IS NULL AND w."w_series"='Series X')` condition
7) by giving a rank to the records and `WHERE rank = 1` condition

Comment: based on the fiddle it looks like this will work, but I did misspeak slightly.  The customers table joins to the customer_data table on a different field. It appears your query isn't utilizing the customer table, but it will ultimately need to.  I'm updating the question now.

Comment: @dscl, I think that your sentence should be starts by 'thanks about the effort to understand my scenario and create tables and populate it with data to make this blah blah ...' +1 for A.B.Cade only by this great job.

Comment: @danihp you are ABSOLUTELY correct!  Thank you A.B.Cade for looking at my problem and working through it. If you can take another look I certainly would appreciate it and if you can't I understand and still appreciate the effort you've already put in.

Comment: @dscl, I updated my answer, added another join to `customers` table and changed the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` condition to map to customers. Another thing I added is the condition to refer to dates of "yesturday" only

Comment: Thanks A.B.Cade - you have no idea how much I appreciate it!

Comment: @A.B.Cade last follow up and once again a big serious thank you... In the case of person cp2 - If they had purchased a second Series X widget on the same day this will omit the Series A, but two records for Series X will result.  Is there a way to drop that down to just return the one result?

Comment: @dscl, I assume that you mean adding another record to `widget_orders` table. If there is nothing to distinguish between those 2 records that can help us know which one is the one we want, then you can just add `distinct` in the select clause. BTW, no need to exaggerate with the "thanks", one will do ;)